# meson: determine running tests as root

Tags: testing, root, meson-build

In tests for [`ping` from iputils](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/test/ping/meson.build) certain tests should *fail* for non-root but *pass* for root. Thus I need a detection whether user *running* tests is root or not. Current code:

```
run_as_root = false
r = run_command('id', '-u')
if r.stdout().strip().to_int() == 0
  message('running as root')
  run_as_root = true
else
  message('running as normal user')
endif

...
test(name, cmd, args : args, should_fail : not run_as_root)
```

is not working, because test is done during build phase:

```
$ meson builddir
The Meson build system
Version: 0.59.4
...
Program xsltproc found: YES (/usr/bin/xsltproc)
Message: running as normal user
```

and not for running tests because root user is not properly detected:

```
# cd builddir/ && meson test
[21/21] Linking target ninfod/ninfod
  1/36 arping -V                             OK              0.03s
...
32/36 ping -c1 -i0.001 127.0.0.1            UNEXPECTEDPASS  0.02s
>>> ./builddir/ping/ping -c1 -i0.001 127.0.0.1

33/36 ping -c1 -i0.001 __1                  UNEXPECTEDPASS  0.02s
```

What to do to evaluate user when running tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a case for skipping rather than expected failure. It would be easy to wrap your tests in a small shell or python script that checks the effective UID and returns the magic exit code 77 (which meson interprets as skip)

Something like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "User does not have root, cannot run"
    exit 77
fi
exec "$@"
```

This will cause `meson test` to return a status of `SKIP` if the tests are not run as root.

Comment: I cannot find code which interprets `127` as skip. Is `127` chosen as POSIX shell exit code `127` when command not found?

Comment: Oops, that's `77` not `127`, I have no idea what I was thinking! https://mesonbuild.com/Unit-tests.html#skipped-tests-and-hard-errors

Comment: Reference for myself: [1cb9d2bc0 ("Support skipped tests")](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/commit/1cb9d2bc0da7ec8c9f37ebd7c2f929ab7afa9e91) (added in 0.37.0).